# Uma única consulta SQL para produtos de um usuário!

Tags: mysql

Tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT id_produto, produto, (SUM(credito) - SUM(debito)) as producao_total 
FROM produtos_farm PF 
INNER JOIN produtos P ON P.id = PF.id_produto 
WHERE PF.id_usuario = 20 AND PF.id_produto = 1
```

Isso me retorna a somatória, nome do produto e id do produto.

Um usuário pode ter até 10 produtos.

Como eu faria para não precisar fazer 10 consultas (um para cada produto)?

> ```
> Tabela PRODUTOS:
> id,
> nome,
> producao,
> preco_padrao
>
> Tabela PRODUTOS_FARM:
> id,
> id_produto,
> id_usuario,
> credito,
> debito
> ```

Comment: Você não consegue adicionar uma cláusula `IN` dos produtos a serem pesquisados? Com isto, você evitaria `n` consultas.

Comment: Eu tentei, mas retorna o mesmo resultado que a consulta que o @rLinhares escreveu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assumindo que `id_produto` identifica cada produto unicamente tente o seguinte:

```
SELECT id_produto, produto, (SUM(credito) - SUM(debito)) as producao_total 
FROM produtos_farm PF 
INNER JOIN produtos P ON P.id = PF.id_produto 
WHERE PF.id_usuario = 20 AND id_produto BETWEEN 1 AND 10
GROUP BY id_produto
```

Nesse caso a produção total do usuário 20 será discriminada por produto. Se só existem 10 produtos no *database* e você quer retornar todos eles a cláusula `AND id_produto BETWEEN 1 AND 10` não é necessária (conforme [a resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/268824/100) do [@rLinhares](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/64073/rlinhares)).

Comment: Perfeito!! E obrigado pela explicação também!!

Answer (score 4):

Basta remover o `id_produto` do `where`, assim você trará todos os produtos do usuário consultado:

```
SELECT id_produto, produto, (SUM(credito) - SUM(debito)) as producao_total 
FROM produtos_farm PF 
INNER JOIN produtos P ON P.id = PF.id_produto 
WHERE PF.id_usuario = 20
GROUP BY id_produto
```

Comment: +1 por essa ser a mesma resposta que a minha.

Comment: Ele dá o resultado da producao_total = 17 (ele junta todos os produtos do usuário). Quero separar a produtao_total para cada produto (1 ao 10).

Comment: Coloca o produto no `SELECT` e faz um `GROUP BY` da coluna. Não resolveria?

Comment: Não entendi @LucasdeSouzaCruz

Comment: No final do SQL, você colocar `GROUP BY ID_PRODUTO, PRODUTO`. Isso iria categorizar as somatórias por produto

Comment: Obrigado @LucasdeSouzaCruz! Deu certo!